How to get original GameObject from the component of that GameOject
I know this seems convoluted but I have a coroutine which takes a RectTransform of a GameObject as an argument and does things with this RectTransform. I want it to also add the original GameObject to a list of GameObjects. I looked online to see if there was a way to get the owner of a component but to no avail. I really want to keep the argument as RectTransform lest I rewrite my entire script.
Here's a snippet of my code so you can get an idea what I mean:
private void ShowGraph(RectTransform activeGraphContainer) {
    graphs.Clear();
    graphs.Add(activeGraphContainer.GetComponent<GameObject>()); //<-- My attempt to get the orignal GameObject (doesn't work)

    //LABEL Y-AXIS -->
    float graphHeight = activeGraphContainer.sizeDelta.y;
    float graphWidth = activeGraphContainer.sizeDelta.x; //<-- example of things the coroutine is doing to the RectTransform


This code explains how to find a specific component in a GameObject, assign it to a variable, and find that object (GameObject) from the variable.
GameObject sample;

void Start()
{
    // In that object, assign the RectTransform Component to the "rectTransform" variable.
    // Find the corresponding object (GameObject) that becomes the parent again in the rectTransform variable and assign it to the sample variable.
    RectTransform rectTransform = this.gameObject.transform.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    sample = rectTransform.gameObject;
}

void Update()
{
    // Find and use the desired component in the “sample” variable.
    float graphHeight = sample.transform.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.y;
    float graphWidth = sample.transform.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.x;
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

GameObject is not a component; it holds the components of your object. Every component has a gameObject property to get it's game object. This is the property you are looking for

Thank you this makes it a lot clearer, I'm not sure how I missed this in the Unity documentation (if it's even there).
